# Why are jobs queued twice by beanstalkd after 2 minutes

Tags: supervisord, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I have the following environment and I notice that the jobs are queued twice randomly after 2 minutes:

- Web App based on PHP F3 framework
- Pheanstalk 3.0.2 using composer in the app
- Beanstalkd server
- Beanstalkd console app
- Supervisord
- Worker scenario: entering multiple jobs to bulk delete clients
- Issue: same job (already processed) is queued twice after 2 minutes with different ID

I use the following code:

```php
$queue =  new Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk("127.0.0.1:14803");
$queue->watch("tubeDelete");
while ($job = $queue->reserve()) {
    $log->write("Entering Job {$job->getId()} \n");
    $log->write("Job {$job->getId()} data : {$job->getData()} \n");
    $data = json_decode($job->getData(), true);
    try {
        $deleteResponse = $client->deleteClient($clientId)
        if($deleteResponse){
            $log->write("client $clientId deleted successfully");
            $queue->delete($job);
        }else{
            $log->write("Failed to delete client $clientId, check the log file");
            $queue->bury($job);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $log->write("Failed to delete client $clientId with PHP exception, check the log file");
        $queue->bury($job);
    }
}
```

Log file:

```
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:23 +0200 Entering Job 92428501
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:23 +0200 Job 92428501 data : {"clientId":"1397"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:24 +0200 Client 1397 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428502
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:24 +0200 Job 92428502 data : {"clientId":"1398"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:26 +0200 Client 1398 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:26 +0200 Entering Job 92428503
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:26 +0200 Job 92428503 data : {"clientId":"1399"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:28 +0200 Client 1399 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:28 +0200 Entering Job 92428504
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:28 +0200 Job 92428504 data : {"clientId":"1401"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:30 +0200 Client 1401 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:30 +0200 Entering Job 92428505
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:30 +0200 Job 92428505 data : {"clientId":"1402"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:31 +0200 Client 1402 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:31 +0200 Entering Job 92428506
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:31 +0200 Job 92428506 data : {"clientId":"1403"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:33 +0200 Client 1403 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:33 +0200 Entering Job 92428507
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:33 +0200 Job 92428507 data : {"clientId":"1404"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:34 +0200 Client 1404 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:34 +0200 Entering Job 92428508
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:34 +0200 Job 92428508 data : {"clientId":"1405"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:36 +0200 Client 1405 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:36 +0200 Entering Job 92428509
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:36 +0200 Job 92428509 data : {"clientId":"1409"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:37 +0200 Client 1409 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:37 +0200 Entering Job 92428510
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:37 +0200 Job 92428510 data : {"clientId":"1421"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:38 +0200 Client 1421 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Entering Job 92428511
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Job 92428511 data : {"clientId":"1397"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Client 1397 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Entering Job 92428512
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Job 92428512 data : {"clientId":"1398"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Client 1398 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Entering Job 92428513
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Job 92428513 data : {"clientId":"1399"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1399 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428514
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Job 92428514 data : {"clientId":"1401"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1401 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428515
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Job 92428515 data : {"clientId":"1402"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1402 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428516
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Job 92428516 data : {"clientId":"1403"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1403 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428517
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Job 92428517 data : {"clientId":"1404"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1404 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428518
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Job 92428518 data : {"clientId":"1405"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1405 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428519
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Job 92428519 data : {"clientId":"1409"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1409 deleted successfully
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Entering Job 92428520
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Job 92428520 data : {"clientId":"1421"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:24 +0200 Client 1421 deleted successfully
```

So, you can find the repeated clients due to executing the same job after 2 minutes, for example:

```
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:23 +0200 Entering Job 92428501
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:23 +0200 Job 92428501 data : {"clientId":"1397"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:00:24 +0200 Client 1397 deleted successfully


Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Entering Job 92428511
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Job 92428511 data : {"clientId":"1397"}
Fri, 08 Dec 2017 13:02:23 +0200 Client 1397 deleted successfully
```

Is it the issue related to TTR / DEADLINE_SOON / configuration issue or related to supervisord?

Comment: There are many things outside of that snippet of code that could effect it. More logging, and meta-data (maybe a UUID& timestamp in the data) being passed through from creation to the logs, being more specific about potential exceptions than can be thrown, and log any `kick`s of buried jobs, would all add to the task.

Comment: What TTR you have set? This is most probably because of a small TTR, try setting 60 seconds, or even 300 seconds and see how it works. If this doesn't resolve then see the producing code.

Comment: The TTR value is the default one